# How to upload images to Firebase and return the URL using React and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, storage, bucket

I want to be able to upload multiple images to Firebase using React Typescript.
The uploadBytes() is throwing some type error which I have been unable to resolve.

Below is my Code

```
type imageUploadType = {
    lastModified: number,
    lastModifiedDate: Date,
    name: string,
    size: string,
    type: string,
    webkitRelativePath: string
}

const initialUploadValues = {
    lastModified: 1688490575474,
    lastModifiedDate: new Date(),
    name: "Gospel TV.png",
    size: '24546',
    type: "image/png",
    webkitRelativePath: ""
}
const Modal = (props: IModalProps) => {
    const user = useContext(UserContext)
    const [imageUpload, setImageUpload] = useState<imageUploadType>(initialUploadValues);
    const [imageUrls, setImageUrls] = useState<Array<string>>([]);


    const imagesListRef = ref(storage, "images/");
    const uploadFile = () => {
        if (imageUpload == null) return;
        const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${imageUpload.name + v4()}`);
        uploadBytes(imageRef, imageUpload).then((snapshot) => {
            getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
                setImageUrls((prev) => [...prev, url]);
            });
        });
    };
}
```

Below is the error

> Argument of type 'imageUploadType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer'.
> Type 'imageUploadType' is missing the following properties from type 'Blob': arrayBuffer, slice, stream, textts(2345)
> const imageUpload: imageUploadType

i tried adding a custom type for the imageUpload state and yet didnt work

Comment: How can I upload multiple images? I am storing them in an array which is the imageUrls but seems not working

Comment: BAsically what I want to do is to be able to upload multiple images to my Firebase storage and return the URL to those image so I can save it in my Database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the docs found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files), it looks like the function `uploadBytes` is expecting a different datatype than you are passing into it. Here is a proposed solution by converting passed in data to a blob:

```
type imageUploadType = {
  lastModified: number,
  lastModifiedDate: Date,
  name: string,
  size: string,
  type: string,
  webkitRelativePath: string
}

const initialUploadValues = {
  lastModified: 1688490575474,
  lastModifiedDate: new Date(),
  name: "Gospel TV.png",
  size: '24546',
  type: "image/png",
  webkitRelativePath: ""
};

const Modal = (props: IModalProps) => {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);
  const [imageUpload, setImageUpload] = useState<imageUploadType>(initialUploadValues);
  const [imageUrls, setImageUrls] = useState<Array<string>>([]);

  const imagesListRef = ref(storage, "images/");

  const convertToBlob = (file: File): Promise<Blob> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        const blob = new Blob([reader.result as ArrayBuffer], { type: file.type });
        resolve(blob);
      };
      reader.onerror = reject;
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
  };

  const uploadFile = async () => {
    if (!imageUpload) return;
    const { name } = imageUpload;
    const file = new File([name], name, { type: imageUpload.type });
    const blob = await convertToBlob(file);
    const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${imageUpload.name + v4()}`);
    
    uploadBytes(imageRef, blob).then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
        setImageUrls((prev) => [...prev, url]);
      });
    });
  };

  // Rest of your component code...

};
```

`convertToBlob` is going to take in a file object and convert it into a blob object. The returned promise resolves with the resulting blob. `uploadFile` now creates a file object using `imageUpload` and passing it to the `convertToBlob` function to obtain the converted Blob before uploading it to Firebase.

One thing to double check is the `convertToBlob` function uses the FileReader API to read the file content. So you can swap this out with whatever else you're currently using to read files, or import it if you're not reading files at all right now.

Comment: Basically what I want to do is to be able to upload multiple images to my Firebase storage and return the URL to those images so I can save them in my Database

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that  `uploadBytes` function expects the image to be formatted as `Blob`, you must convert the image file to `Blob` before running your function `uploadBytes`

`const fileBlob = new Blob([urlImageToUpload], { type: urlImageToUpload.type });`
this it's the documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Blob